# declare 2d variable Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, assign

I am wondering whether it is possible to assign a value to a variable that would point to some exact position in the 2d Array in Java. 
I am accessing array element through

```
imageMatrix[width][hight].getColor1()
```

and since I am considering different scenarios, it would be easier to declare [width][high] by eg. `n1=[2][1]` and then call

```
imageMatrix(n1).getColor1()
```

Is it somehow possible? Thanks!

Comment: `imageMatrix[widht][height].getColor1()` is not a method, but the access of an array element, calling `cetColor1()` on the accessed array element. You can define a method `imageMatrix(...)` with some parameter of fitting type (e.g. [`Pair<Integer, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) or some self-written class).

Comment: Use OOP. Write class what will contain both x and y - Point f.e. Then you can write methods which will receive Point objects.

Comment: In short as @Turing85 is eluding to.  No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class Coordinate that contains the width and height of a cell of your 2d array. Then use an instance of this class to your imageMatrix() method.

Something like:

```
public clas Coordinate{
    private int height;
    private int width;
/*Accessors and constructors...*/


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I am clearly missing something. If I define  `public void Point(int width, int height) { this.width=width; this.height=height;}` and then with `Point n1= new Point(3,3);` try to call `imageMatrix(n1).getColor1()` I still get error "The method imageMatrix(Point) is undefined for the type Picture"

Answer (score 0):

You can define ImageMatrix and Point as class.
For setting and getting color of each point you can create method inside Point class.
Here we are storing each point in a list so that we can access them in future.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ImageMatrix {
    Point point;
    public ImageMatrix(Point point){
        this.point = point;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //to set color and store each point into a list
        ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<>();
        //creating 9 points with different color
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                Point point = new Point(i,j);
                point.setColor("color"+i+j);
                pointList.add(point);
            }
        }
        //to get color from each point
        for(Point point : pointList){
            System.out.println("color of point " + point.height +" and " + point.width +" is : " + point.getColor());
        }
    }
}

class Point{
    public int height;
    public int width;
    public String color;

    public Point(int height, int width){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String getColor(){
         return this.color;
    }
}
```